# How do I enter DFU mode on an iPhone 3G OS 4.2.1?

Tags: iphone

I've tried several solutions to enter DFU mode but none worked:
- the Home + Sleep combo
- the DFU program [here](http://modmyi.com/forums/general/488021-enter-dfu-mode-without-sleep-wake-button.html)

Somebody has an idea?

Comment: Just to add I have been trying to get my iPhone 3G (just upgraded to 4.2.1) into DFU mode too using all of the methods on YouTube, using the counting assists, etc. but they don't work. Perhaps DFU mode might have been written out of the firmware or something? That's the way it seems to me, anyway. Whenever I press my power button now, plugged in or not, the phone just starts up straight away after a couple of seconds—no period of black.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that these instructions still work with iTunes 12.4 and an iPhone 3G with iOS 4.0.2? I am unable to achieve DFU with that combo.

Answer (score 4):

DFU has always worked as follows:

1. Turn off the phone
2. Hold power and Home for 10 seconds (exactly 10 seconds, use a clock with seconds)
3. Release Power, but keep holding Home
4. After 5-10 seconds you should get the phone detected on the computer with the screen still black.

I've tested this on 2G, 3G, 3Gs and works on all of them fine.

Here's a video on how to do DFU properly: [iPhone DFU Mode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gl5mXtmBusE)

Also I just like to note that this procedure must not be mistaken for recovery mode (iTunes cable screen), which is done by:

1. Hold Home
2. Keep holding Home, press power to start the device (1-2 sec is enough)
3. Release power, keep holding Home until you get to the iTunes cable screen

Answer (score 0):

This is not DFU, this is recovery mode.
DFU is:
- 2 sec Power
- 10 sec Power + Home
- 15 sec Home

And it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You should have added this as a comment on the answer. You still can delete this and do it properly! ;)

Comment: Actually what you say will most likely put you in recovery. DFU mode is just as I answered above. Recovery is: Hold home, press and hold power for 1-2 sec to start the device, release power -> iTunes cable (recovery). Try what I said above. I've tried it thousands of times and it works - here's a video on how to do DFU properly: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gl5mXtmBusE

Comment: You are aware that DFU mode results in a blank screen, right? The only way to tell if the iDevice is actually in DFU mode is to have it connected to a desktop PC.