# Remove Jailbreak?

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak

I used redsn0w to get an untethered jailbreak on my iPod touch. And now I want to remove it.

I've seen people mention that you need to backup the iPod to iTunes and then restore it. However, when you restore it, iTunes will install the latest OS (5.1) on the device. This isn't good if you plan on jailbreaking again in the future (i.e. you want to leave it on 5.0.1). So is there any other way I could remove the jailbreak from the device and keep 5.0.1 on the iPod? Would using "Erasing all content and settings" on the iPod work?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, you have to restore your device in order to remove the jailbreak.

But it's not that easy to restore to an earlier version of iOS - Apple verifies each restore of iOS and only lets you restore to the latest version (currently iOS 5.1). If you want to restore to an earlier version, you have to artificially verify the restore.

For an iPod touch, you can artificially verify the restore if you have pre-saved SHSH blobs for the device, by stitching them into custom firmware and using that to restore. Here's a [guide to seeing if Cydia managed to save SHSH blobs for you and using them to restore your device](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/32462/frequently-asked-questions#94647). If Cydia didn't save SHSH blobs for you, you may be able to use redsn0w or iFaith to "dump" partial iOS 5.0.1 SHSH blobs off your device and then use them to stitch a custom IPSW - see [this guide to using iFaith](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/32462/frequently-asked-questions#45545).

Comment: This is correct, and those links are up-to-date, too.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/46017/11600) holds a part of the answer. Basically you have to restore your device.

Is you want to install a particular version of iOS on your device then you will have to locate the official firmware on your hard drive (`.ipsw` file) or download it from Apple.

Then instead of restoring like usual you will have to hold the option key, hit restore and then you will be given the opportunity to select the file to use for the restore.

Comment: This won't work unless Apple is signing iOS 5.0.1 (which they're not), sorry.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson. Well then a 3rd party firmware tool will be necessary.

Comment: Yes, you need to insert your SHSH blobs into the `.ipsw` using a tool such as iFaith.