# Can I make Chrome the default web browser in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome

With Google Chrome available for iOS now I'd like to know if it's possible to make Chrome the default browser? I find "open in browser" type options from other iOS apps still take me to Safari.

Not interested in jailbreaking. Looking for a solution that works without having to do that.

Comment: JailBreaking is the only way right now, sorry.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I'm actually thinking it's time to try the JB route...

Comment: If you do plan on going down that path, I've [answered a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46044/18387) that explains what JailBreaking does and what reversing it does. Feel free to ask me any questions here on AskDifferent or on chat if you run into any problems or concerns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not possible unless Apple allows this in a future iOS update.

Comment: Are you suggesting that they will?

Comment: @user1090389 There's no reason to believe that they will, but there's no reason to rule out the possibility.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like they eventually did... iOS 14

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different and thanks for adding an up-to-date answer! You should add instructions on how to enable this feature in iOS 14, so the asker—and anyone else who discovers this question—actually knows what to do!