# Removing Jailbreak from iPod touch 4g 8gb

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak

So I wanted to play some pokemon games on my iPod touch, and I jailbreaked it with redsn0w 0.9.15b3.
In the end I couldn't use neither safari nor anything apple related(plus my home key isn't working as it should and I couldn't "just root" it).
Now, I want to know how to remove jailbreak. I don't care if any data is lost or anything.
It's iPod 4G 8gb and I can't install iOs7 'cause of that.

Comment: Restore it with iTunes. That's all you have to do. See my answer here for more information: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46044/18387

Answer (score 1):

Just use iTunes and restore it.
You could also use your jailbrooken backup to get your saves and stuff back, or just start a clean one and let iCloud sync contacts and primary stuff back.

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade the iOS if you haven't already. Or restore it using iTunes. Or you could reset the iPod by holding both power and home buttons until it gets to the lock screen.